# Find a power series solution centered at 0 (Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Here's the problem: $$(x-1)y''+y'=0$$  This is the work that I've already done: $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+1})(n+1)x^n$$
$$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^n$$
I then plug those into the original equation:
$$(x-1)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+1})(n+1)x^n=0$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+1})(n+1)x^n=0$$
And this is where I'm stuck and don't know what to do from here. If someone could help me out that would be great.

Comment: Pull out the first terms from the last two sums, then combine all the sums into one.

Comment: Like this? $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(a_{n+2})(n+1)-(a_{n+1})(n+1)]x^n=0$$

Comment: You still need to separate the first term from the sum on the right.  Then, once you've done that, combine that sum with the one on the left.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure I follow. Could you write it out for me? Maybe once I see what you're talking about I'll understand :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting 
$$
y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n,
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
(x-1)y''(x)+y'(x)&=&(x-1)\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}\\
&=&\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2a_nx^{n-1}-\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)^2a_{n+1}x^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}x^n\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)[(n+2)a_{n+2}-(n+1)a_{n+1}]x^n.
\end{eqnarray}
Therefore
$$
(x-1)y''(x)+y'(x)=0 \iff a_{n+2}=\frac{n+1}{n+2}a_{n+1} \quad \forall n\ge 0,
$$
i.e.
$$
a_n=\frac{n-1}{n}a_{n-1} \quad \forall n\ge 2.
$$
Thus
$$
a_n=\frac{(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\ldots(2-1)}{n\cdot(n-1)\ldots(2-1)}a_1=\frac{1}{n}a_1 \quad \forall n \ge 2.
$$
The solution of the DE is then given by
$$
y(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_1\sum_{n=2}\frac{1}{n}x^n=a_0+a_1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}x^n\equiv a_0-a_1\ln(1-x),
$$
where $a_0,a_1$ are real constants.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+1}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+1})(n+1)x^n = 0.
$$

Rewrite the first sum as

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^{n+1} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(a_{m+1})(m+1)(m)x^m.
$$

Rewrite the second sum as

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^n &= 2a_2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+2})(n+2)(n+1)x^n \\
&= 2a_2 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(a_{m+2})(m+2)(m+1)x^m.
\end{align}
$$

Rewrite the third sum as

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a_{n+1})(n+1)x^n &= a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n+1})(n+1)x^n \\
&= a_1 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(a_{m+1})(m+1)x^m.
\end{align}
$$

The first expression thus becomes

$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(a_{m+1})(m+1)(m)x^m - 2a_2 - \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(a_{m+2})(m+2)(m+1)x^m + a_1 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(a_{m+1})(m+1)x^m = 0.
$$

Now combine the sums to get

$$
a_1 - 2a_2 + \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \Bigl[ m(m+1)a_{m+1} - (m+1)(m+2)a_{m+2} + (m+1)a_{m+1} \Bigr] x^m = 0.
$$

Comment: I'm getting a really weird recursion, so I don't really trust my answer.
$$a_{n+2}={(a_{n+1})(n)+(a_{n+1})\over (n+2)}$$
Does that look right? If it is, I'm not sensing a pattern.

Comment: Yup, seems right to me.  Try rewriting it as $a_{n+2} = \frac{n+1}{n+2} a_{n+1}$ and calculate the first few, $a_2, a_3, a_4$, etc.

Comment: For my final answer, I'm left with an $a_{0}, a_{1}, a_{2}$ and wouldn't that make it a third order differential equation?

Comment: You're just left with $a_0$ and $a_1$.  The coefficient $a_2$ is determined by $a_1 - 2a_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, it is easier to go this way:

i) make the substitution $z=y'$ to reduce the order of the ode and deal with the new ode

> $$ (x-1)z'+z=0. $$

ii) use power series technique to solve the above ode by assuming

> $$z(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n .$$

iii) Use $z=y'$ to get $y(x)$.